# No main() in c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

The issue I'm having is trying to find the run order for a number of classes in a project. There is no explicit main and I have looked in obj/debug and found nothing which might have been generated at compile time. Have you any ideas where I might find something. Also I cannot find any xaml files either. It's a console function.

Comment: Most .NET decompilers will show the entry point for a module.

Comment: c# is a language, not a project. What is your project type? Please change the title

Comment: @Liel I don't think I agree with the point you are making. I don't think saying "C# project" implies that the OP is saying it is a C# project rather than a Web Application/Console Application/etc. It is a C# project rather than VB.NET or C++. I will agree that the title could be re-worked though, and it is possible that the OP did mean what you implied... but we can't be sure without clarification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a quick way to find the entry point (if there is one):

Without any specific source file open, press <kbd>F11</kbd> to start the debugger at the first line. This should make your entry point obvious.

---

Note that if this is a Console Application like you said, there must be a `static` main() method.

Here is the documentation for [`Main()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx):

> The Main method is the entry point of a C# console application or windows application. (Libraries and services do not require a Main method as an entry point.). When the application is started, the Main method is the first method that is invoked.

Comment: @zimdanen I discovered it on accident one day when I thought I was already debugging, and was using it as the "step into" shortcut. Turns out, when not debugging, it will "step into" the entry point.

Answer (score 10):

If you check the project properties, under "Application", there is a "Startup object" listed.  This should tell you the *entry point* to the application, which is the type which contains the `Main` method that is actually being used.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a console application then you will usually find the `Main` method in the auto-generated `Program.cs` file.

If there is no `main` method, the project is a class library.

Other than @Gray's answer, you could also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for `Main`.